# FluentSecurity and Ninject

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, fluent-security

```
Error activating IntPtr
```

I'm trying to configure FluentSecurity (v.1.4) with Ninject (v.3) in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

I can't set up the `ResolveServicesUsing()` configuration expression without throwing the above error.

```
SecurityConfigurator.Configure(
    configuration =>
        {
            configuration.ResolveServicesUsing(
                DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices, 
                DependencyResolver.Current.GetService);
...
```

I've also tried using another overload for `ResolveServicesUsing()`

```
configuration.ResolveServicesUsing(
    type => DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices(type));
```

FluentSecurity needs to be configured with Ninject to inject the method for finding my users' roles and also for the PolicyViolationHandler implementations.

**UPDATE**

I've found I can leave out the offending lines and still have my GetRolesFrom() implementation called (hurrah):

```
configuration.GetRolesFrom(
    () =>
    ((IPersonManager)DependencyResolver
    .Current
    .GetService(typeof(IPersonManager)))
    .GetCurrentUserRoles());
```

I still can't get my PolicyViolationHandler to work, however:

```
public class RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler : IPolicyViolationHandler
{
    public ActionResult Handle(PolicyViolationException exception)
    {
        return new RedirectToRouteResult(
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                    {
                        action = "AccessDenied", 
                        controller = "Home"
                    }));
    }
}
```

I'm doing the binding in a NinjectModule like this:

```
public class SecurityModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Kernel.Bind<IPolicyViolationHandler>()
                   .To<RequireRolePolicyViolationHandler>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured MVC's DependencyResolver to point at Ninject?  I'm not familiar with Ninject but there is usually a call to DependencyResolver.SetResolver(IDependencyResolver) in app start, where you pass in an implementation that wraps Ninject's methods to resolve service/type registrations.

Comment: It certainly seems to be as I can use the DependencyResolver to call another method but as a check I found the source code for the ninject.web.mvc3 build and it looks as if the System.Web.Mvc DependencyResolver is being set:
    `NinjectMvcHttpApplicationPlugin Start() { DependencyResolver.SetResolver(this.CreateDependencyResolver()); }`

Answer (score 1):

> Error activating IntPtr

Unfortunately you havn't posted the complete StackTrace. But usually you  will get this exception when injecting a `Func` to some class without having a binding or using the Factory extension.

Answer (score 0):

I use Fluent Security with Ninject as IOC container.

In your Fluent Security configuration, you need to set the service locator to the NinjectServiceLocator.

```
    public static void Configure(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var locator = new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel);
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => locator);

        SecurityConfigurator.Configure(
            configuration =>
            {
                configuration.GetAuthenticationStatusFrom(() => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated);

     ....
    }
```

You can get the locator [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator.NinjectAdapter/).

Hope this helps